# Resource folder is not access in C#.

Tags: c#

i am facing issue while set picture to my notifier. it cannot access the Resource folder where my picture is save and also i can not access Resource after going to properties of my project.[Project property error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiW43.png)
[Error in my code where i cannot access Resource folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8cBG.png)

Answer (score 0):

In c# code statement is separated by ; On second statement you don't have any text after Propeties.

So this problem is causing by that.

By checking another screenshot It's look like you have different namespace in Default Namespace under your application properties which doesn't match with the namespace you have all your app.

Comment: That's not a problem because i want to access Resource after that.like Properties.Resources.imagefile

Comment: You have different namespace in Default Namespace in Application properties than all over your app. Match it, 2-3 days ago I stuck on same issue.